# Google Maps API - Overlay polygon at a specific elevation with opacity (to show flooded areas)

Tags: google-maps, polygon, elevation

Using the Google Maps API, I'm trying to work out how to draw a polygon over a Google map at a specific elevation using opacity so that any land mass that is *below* the elevation of the polygon shows as highlighted while the land that is *above* it will not show as highlighted (I hope to be able to use a polygon at 40% Opacity to do this.)

So for example, if I draw a polygon at 100m over a landmass that ranges from, say 95m to 105m all land in the polygon that is *under* 100m should be highlighted and all that *above* it should not be.

This is to enable our underwriters to see, at various flood levels above a water source, whether one or more properties covered by insurance would be flooded.

This can be done very easily in Google Earth and in the GE API but unfortunately we are deploying this app to thin clients through a Citrix client which does not allow us to install or use the Google Earth Plugin... talk about making life hard!! :-(

I have googled this numerous times and multiple ways and found nothing - pretty much starting to think it can't be done - very much hoping someone can help me out and prove me wrong!

Comment: How can it be done in Google Earth?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out by chance?  I would also love to know the answer.

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.4.3_sea-level.html

Comment: No sorry, I never did - the project I was doing on flood analysis was abandoned because we couldn't get this working.